# Cannot run bootstrap.sh when building Boost on Centos 7

Tags: c++, boost, centos, b2

I'm trying to build the Boost libraries (version 1_78_0) on a virtual Centos 7 machine, using gcc/g++ 8.3.1. I've installed the usual development tools to build the libraries but continually get the error message below when running ./bootstrap.sh:

Too many input files

Compilation terminated

Can anyone suggest a way round this?

```
[root@flametreeapidev boost_1_78_0]# ./bootstrap.sh
Building B2 engine..

###
###
Using 'cxx' toolset.
###
###

cpp (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


###
###

cpp -DNDEBUG builtins.cpp class.cpp command.cpp compile.cpp constants.cpp cwd.cpp debug.cpp debugger.cpp execcmd.cpp execnt.cpp execunix.cpp filesys.cpp filent.cpp fileunix.cpp frames.cpp function.cpp glob.cpp hash.cpp hcache.cpp hdrmacro.cpp headers.cpp jam_strings.cpp jam.cpp jamgram.cpp lists.cpp make.cpp make1.cpp md5.cpp mem.cpp modules.cpp native.cpp object.cpp option.cpp output.cpp parse.cpp pathnt.cpp pathsys.cpp pathunix.cpp regexp.cpp rules.cpp scan.cpp search.cpp startup.cpp subst.cpp sysinfo.cpp timestamp.cpp variable.cpp w32_getreg.cpp modules/order.cpp modules/path.cpp modules/property-set.cpp modules/regex.cpp modules/sequence.cpp modules/set.cpp -o b2

cpp: fatal error: too many input files

compilation terminated.

cp b2 bjam

cp: cannot stat ‘b2’: No such file or directory

Failed to build B2 build engine
[root@flametreeapidev boost_1_78_0]#
```

Comment: See https://github.com/boostorg/build/issues/614